# How to combine ODEX and VDEX files with an APK file?

Tags: apk, rom, system-apps, android-10, odex

I have an **.apk** file, also comes with it two files, one **.odex** files, another **.vdex** file. The files were pulled from the **/system/app** folder of another phone.

The files hierarchy on the original system is like this:

`/system/app/FM2/FM2.apk
/system/app/FM2/oat/arm64/FM2.odex
/system/app/FM2/oat/arm64/FM2.vdex`

What I want to do here is to **combine all these files into a single APK file**, so that I may be able to install it on other phones.

(*Let's ignore for the moment that the other phone may not have the required dependency installed on it*)

**So, how can I combine *.apk*, *.odex*, and *.vdex* files together into a single *.apk* file?**

**P.S.** I have read some articles about using smali and baksmali to convert odex to dex and vice-versa, but I couln't find the detailed tutorial that I need. Also, these articles never talk about VDEX files, which is an issue here.

**P.P.S.** Both the source and destination phones are exactly the same with Android 10, but different regions.

Comment: Did you already try to install the actual .apk to the target device?

Comment: Yes I tried. The apk installs successfully, but it doesnt open. When I click on its icon, nothing happens except a nanosecond flash of black colour. Then I'm back to home screen.

Comment: Check the logcat for the precise error.

Comment: `odex` file is the Ahead of Time Compiled binary code and `vdex` is a supportive file. Both are not packaged with `.apk` file but generated by compiler (`dex2oat`) after installation or after a few runs. So they should not be the reason for failure. But mostly system apps cannot be installed as ordinary user apps due to lack of privileges and permissions.